# How to write a file download to response in JSP file

Tags: jsp, download

I'm getting a java.lang.IllegalStateException when I try to get a ServletOutputStream object from the response object.  Below is my code:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>             

<%
try {
    System.out.print("request came");
    File f = new File ("E:/dd.txt");

    String name = f.getName().substring(f.getName().lastIndexOf("/") + 1,f.getName().length());
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);

    ServletOutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();

    response.setContentType ("application/txt");
    response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+f.getName()+"");
    int bit = 256;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        while ((bit) >= 0) {
            bit = in.read();
            outs.write(bit);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    outs.flush();
    outs.close();
    in.close();         
} catch (Exception ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
%>
```

The following is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.ServletResponseWrapperInclude.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapperInclude.java:63)
   at org.apache.jsp.html.portlet.vitage.custom.QUADWAVE.Procfiledownloadess1_005f36901_005f48.filedownload.downloadscreen_jsp._jspService(downloadscreen_jsp.java:5
   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Comment: r u trying to download file using JSP?

Comment: It actually surprises me that you initially tagged the question with `[servlets]` (which is the correct answer to your question!) even though you are not using a servlet at all, but a JSP file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1776268/733092 for a quick answer that works.

Answer (score 6):

You're attempting to download a file by some code in a JSP file. JSP as being a view technology is actually the wrong tool for the job. Everything outside `<% %>` (which is normally text based content like HTML, XML, JSON, etc) is written to the HTTP response as well, **including whitespace**. This would only corrupt the integrity of the downloaded content which is written by Java code, even more so if you're serving binary files such as document/audio/video files.

Your concrete problem is caused because JSP internally uses `response.getWriter()` to print all the template content (everything outside `<% %>`) and then you're attempting to use `getOutputStream()`. This is an illegal state. You can't use them both simultaneously on a single response. Apart from using `getWriter()` instead, you could solve it by removing **any** whitespace outside `<% %>`, including newlines.

So, replace

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>             

<%
    // Your Java code.
%>
```

by

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%><%
    // Your Java code.
%>
```

*(and make absolutely sure that there's no trailing whitespace/newline after the last `%>` as well)*

However, you should actually not be using JSP for the job. It's as said the wrong tool for the job. You should be using a normal [HTTP servlet class](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for the job. Just create a class extending `HttpServlet` and move all the Java code which you've there in the JSP into the `doGet()` method. Finally map that servlet on an URL and invoke that URL instead.

```
@WebServlet("/download")
public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Your Java code.
    }

}
```

You can find a more concrete example in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html).

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/)
- [Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java/)
- [How to stream audio/video files such as MP3, MP4, AVI, etc using a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588149/how-to-stream-audio-video-files-such-as-mp3-mp4-avi-etc-using-a-servlet)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest writing the file download code in the servlet. Something like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        ServletContext sc = request.getServletContext();
        String logFilename = (String) sc.getAttribute("scriptFilename");
        String logFilepath = DOWNLOAD_DIR + File.separator + logFilename + LOGFILE_EXTN;
               log.debug("file name received: "+logFilename);
               log.debug("log file path: "+logFilepath);

        File logFile = new File(logFilepath);
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;

        if(logFile.exists() && logFile.length()!=0) {

            log.debug(logFile.getName()+": file exits in the directory.");
            String MIME_TYPE = "application/octet-stream";
            response.setContentType(MIME_TYPE);

            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", logFile.getName());
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

            try {

                outStream = response.getOutputStream();
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(logFile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

            }catch(IOException io) {

                log.debug("exception occured.."+io.getMessage());

            } finally {

                if(inputStream != null) {

                    inputStream.close();
                }

                outStream.flush();
                if(outStream != null) {

                    outStream.close();
                }
            }

        }else {

            log.debug(logFile.getName()+" :file not found in the directory.");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "Jmeter Log file not found");
        }
    }
```

And you can have a button in your jsp say 'download' where onclick, the above servlet should be called.
In this way you can have the logs getting printed in JSP.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the error because `response.getWriter();` was already called before `response.getOutputStream();`. It is illegal to call both `getWriter()` and `getOutputStream()` in a service call. And JSP's, by default use `getWriter()` .

Try replacing

```
ServletOutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();
```

with

```
PrintWriter outs = response.getWriter();
```

Comment: It would still end up in a corrupted file.

Comment: When I use this solution, it says that incompatible type. Required ServletOutputStream found PrintWriter.

Comment: Replace ServletOutputStream with PrintWriter.

Answer (score -1):

1. did you tried using "out" which is implicitly present on jsp?
2. Does your program has permissions to read files from disk?

Thanks, 
Prateek

Comment: You did not answer the question. Both of your points are not realted to IllegalStateException.