# Why my .jsp file Unable to display pdf on page not download

Tags: java, jsp, pdf

this my code for preview pdf on page jsp

i try to convert base64 -> byte -> pdf but don't work

```
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer responsePDF = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            responsePDF.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responsePDF.toString());
        output = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("output").getString("output");
        System.out.println("Into if Status OK");
        System.out.println("output in JSP is = "  + output);
        b64 = output;
        decoder = Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64);
        
        
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline"; filename=\"Test.pdf\"");
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        Collection<String> headerNamesCollection2 = response.getHeaderNames();
        Enumeration<String> headerNames2 = Collections.enumeration(headerNamesCollection2);
        while (headerNames2.hasMoreElements()) 
        {
            String headerName2 = headerNames2.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Header2 Name: " + headerName2);
            String headerValue2 = response.getHeader(headerName2);
            System.out.println("Header2 Value: " + headerValue2);
        }
    
        
        ServletOutputStream serv_out = response.getOutputStream();
        serv_out.write(decoder);
        serv_out.flush();
        //serv_out.close();
        //out.clear();
        


    } else {
       System.out.println("Failed to get the response. Response code: " + responseCode);
    }
    
    connection.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

my page display like this

[image: my pdf page]

i'm clearly sure my base64 and binary no somthing wrong they can convert to pdf in online platfrom

but idk why my response header can't set

this is what i expect

to show reprot pdf on my page

Comment: JSP is the wrong tool for this. It will easily corrupt any binary data with whitespace coming from scriptlet tags. Just use a Servlet. See abovelinked duplicate.

Comment: This is my Response Header 
 Content-Type = text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding =  gzip

idk why Header response dose'nt set

Comment: It's because you used JSP instead of Servlet for this. JSP is designed to print text/html. Just put Java code in a normal Java class instead of a JSP file. See abovelinked duplicate. More specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110665