# Call ContainerRequestFilter on Tomcat's own DefaultServlet

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

Following [BalusC's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) instructions on that answer:

[How to stream audio/video files such as MP3, MP4, AVI, etc using a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588149/how-to-stream-audio-video-files-such-as-mp3-mp4-avi-etc-using-a-servlet)

I added the following `Context` element to my Tomcat `server.xml` to make my media files available to Tomcat's own `DefaultServlet`.

```
<Context docBase="/home/jwi/media" path="/service/media" />
```

This works like charm and the media is available at:

```
http://localhost:8080/service/media/example.mp4
```

The `ApplicationPath` from my application (build on Jersey 2.x) is set to: `@ApplicationPath("service")`.

Within that application I have a request filter that checks every incoming request for a valid user session.

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
@Priority(1)
public class SessionFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ServletContext _context;
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest _request;
    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse _response;

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        HttpSession session = _request.getSession(false);
        boolean isLoggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("username") != null;
        boolean isLoginRequest = _request.getRequestURI().contains("login");

        if (isLoggedIn || isLoginRequest) {
            // Since filter chain is invoked by @Priority annotation here's nothing to do.
        } else {
            URI indexPage = UriBuilder.fromUri("/index.html").build();
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.temporaryRedirect(indexPage).build());
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, that filter is never called on the media elements. So when I open `http://localhost:8080/service/media/example.mp4` the filter isn't called at all.

How do I add Tomcat's DefaultServlet to my request filter?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a Servlet [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) instead?

```java
@WebFilter("/service/media/*")
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        ...

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Comment: That's why I mentioned the @ApplicationPath Annoation in my issue above. The ApplicationPath is set to 'service' and the media path in server.xml is also set to '/service/media'. Normaly the RequestFilter should catch every request starting with 'service' as request uri.

Comment: @jwi I think I misread your question. Have you tried the Servlet `Filter`?

Comment: I thought it would be just fine if the media path inside the server.xml starts with the ApplicationPath from my JAX-RS application - this doesn't work. I'll try now your advice with the Servlet Filter. ;)

Comment: Implemented the WebFilter but the requests still don't get caught by the filter. :/